# Compare dataframe values to aggregated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called allData which contains thousands of rows of trial info/data pertaining to thousands of files of x,y,z trajectory data.

Each row contains:

1. obsScenario: 0, 1 or 2
2. startPos: 1 or 2
3. targetPos: 1, 2, or 3
4. cumDist: float64 value of cumulative distance traveled for that trajectory

For each obsScenario, there are the 2 start positions and the 3 target positions, so each obstacle scenario has 6 trials (1 X 2 X 3).

**allData** looks like this:

```
    obsScenario  startPos  targetPos    cumDist
0            0         1          1  33.797209
1            2         1          1  34.941458
2            2         1          2  34.153108
3            2         2          1  37.489698
4            0         1          1  35.099954
5            0         1          3  37.368709
6            2         1          1  33.421624
7            0         1          2  32.491703
8            1         2          1  37.268338
9            2         2          2  34.414690
...
```

I created a second dataFrame, allData_avg to get the average cumulative distance, grouped by variables 1-3 (obsScenario, startPos, targetPos) using:

```
allData_avg = allData.groupby(['obsScenario', 'startPos', 'targetPos']).agg([np.average])
```

**allData_avg** looks like this:

```
                                  cumDist
                                  average
obsScenario startPos targetPos           
0           1        1          34.236374
                     2          33.360685
                     3          40.131592
            2        1          39.493517
                     2          34.034068
                     3          34.835779
1           1        1          34.290811
                     2          34.100946
                     3          39.116431
            2        1          38.641681
```

I am now trying to use these averages to filter out trajectories from allData that have a cumulative distance 1.25x greater/larger than the average pertaining to that trial's specific combination of obsScenario, startPos, and targetPos values (this is to filter out participant trajectories that are weird/bad).

So for example, for index 5 of allData, the cumDist 37.37 needs to be < 1.25 * 40.13. If not, then that entire row of data should be deleted from the original dataframe allData.

I've been trying to do this for a while and am stumped. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel(r"D:\Stack_overflow\test10.xlsx")


df['avg_cum']=df.groupby(['obsScenario', 'startPos', 'targetPos'])['cumDist'].transform('mean') #ADDING AVERAGE OF CUMDIST COLUMN BASED ON THE COMBINATION

df.loc[df['cumDist'] < df['avg_cum']*1.25] #FILTER BASED ON THE VALUE
```

This is how We can filter out the values based on cumulative columns which is being added newly.
I am not sure About the value 40.13 how have you achieved, probably it is the average of all data whereas i have performed actions on first 9-10 rows which has been listed in the question.

Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i never would have thought that would work! Much simpler than what i was trying. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be the most optimised solution but it will give you an idea of how to go about it.

```
rows_to_be_deleted = []

for i, row in allData.iterrows():

    obsScenario = row['obsScenario']
    startPos = row['startPos']
    targetPos = row['targetPos']

    cumDistAvg = allData_avg.loc[obsScenario].loc[startPos].loc[targetPos]['cumDist'].loc['average']

    if row['cumDist'] >= (1.25 * cumDistAvg):
        rows_to_be_deleted.append(i)

allData_filtered = allData.drop(rows_to_be_deleted)
```